# Spring Security 4.x , Dynamic InvalidSessionUrl

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

My project has 2 user roles: [ADMIN, COURT] and unauthenticated (anonymous?) users. ADMIN has super-admin access, i.e. global access. COURT has access to specific pages. Both ADMIN and COURT are authenticated.

The problem is that session timeouts need to be handled differently for these three populations: the ADMIN and COURT users need to re-direct to their respective login pages, and unauthenticated sessions need to be directed to a contextual home page (/xyz/home) based on the previous context.

I've googled this topic, and can't seem to find a mention of this concept and solution. As far as I can see from research, the session management invalid session url controls this behaviour, but I need dynamic value here, so that I can control the landing point.

My code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private MongoUserService mongoUserService;

@Autowired
private LoginAuthenticationEntryPoint loginEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler;

@Autowired
private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(loginEntryPoint)
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/court/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**/court/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","COURT")
            .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/dologin")
                .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/dologout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(false)
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/")
                .maximumSessions(1)
        ;
}

@Override
@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(mongoUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Component
public class LoginAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    public LoginAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        // LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint requires a default
        super("/");
    }

    /**
     * @param request   the request
     * @param response  the response
     * @param exception the exception
     * @return the URL (cannot be null or empty; defaults to {@link #getLoginFormUrl()})
     */
    @Override
    protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                 AuthenticationException exception) {
        String requestUrl = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println("in LoginAuthenticationEntryPoint, requestUrl = " + requestUrl);
        if (requestUrl.indexOf("/admin") != -1) {
            return "/admin/login";
        }
        else if (requestUrl.indexOf("/court") != -1) {
            return "/court/login";
        }
        else {
            return "/admin/login";
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        setDefaultFailureUrl(getFailureUrl(request));
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }

    private String getFailureUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String refererUrl = request.getHeader("Referer");
        System.out.println("in AuthenticationFailureHandler, referrerUrl: " + refererUrl);
        if (refererUrl.indexOf("/admin") != -1) {
            return "/admin/login?err=1";
        }
        else if (refererUrl.indexOf("/court") != -1) {
            return "/court/login?err=1";
        }
        else {
            return "/admin/login?err=1";
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class LogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    public LogoutSuccessHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        setDefaultTargetUrl(request.getHeader("Referer"));
        handle(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE:

When I attempted to miplement a custom ConcurrentSessionFilter, I received an exception. This is the code, with the resulting stack trace below:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentSessionFilter customConcurrentSessionFilter() {
    return new CustomConcurrentSessionFilter();
}

public class CustomConcurrentSessionFilter extends ConcurrentSessionFilter {

    protected String determineExpiredUrl(HttpServletRequest request, SessionInformation info) {
        return "something here";
    }
}
```

the exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customConcurrentSessionFilter' defined in class path resource [com/cii/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SessionRegistry required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SessionRegistry required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.afterPropertiesSet(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: First of all your `LogoutSuccessHandler` and `AuthenticationFailureHandler` are flawed, they won't work in a high concurrent environment. You are resetting the default URL each time now imagine a user and admin coming in at the same time, one change overrides the other and the user might go to the admin page (or vice versa). But to answer your question, create a custom `ConcurrentSessionFilter` and override the `determineExpiredUrl` method.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. Hoeever, I'm having trouble implementing a custom ConcurrentSessionFilter; I'm seeing exceptions upon initialization. I've been running on fumes the last few days, so apologies if this should be easy/straightforward. Can you give me a more explicit example?

Comment: Please add the errors. When using custom classes you cannot use the `sessionManagement()` method to configure things but have to fully configure the filter by hand and use the `addFilterBefore` method to have it added.

Comment: Code and errors included above